# Dx Could not locate '../google-play-services_lib.jar'. This will not be added to the package

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using the Google play services in my Eclipse project. I added this after I checked Is Library and built it. There are no build errors. But when I run then I get 
"Could not find mytest.apk!"

When I clean and rebuild I get
 Dx Could not locate '../google-play-services_lib.jar'. This will not be added to the package

I have added the following in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Build that project first, then yours.

Comment: Jeremy, I am not sure I understand.I have built my project and there are no errors. It is only when I run I get the could not find the *.apk.

Comment: When you import the Google Play Services project, you also need to build it -- that makes the jar file.  After that, you can attach it to you project and build that.

Answer (score 0):

First if you would like to use google play service in your project then you should be build and jar should be created.

```
1. Create Eclipes project to build Google play service
2. Go to Project properties >> Android >> Check "Is Library"
3. Build the project 
4. You will see jar file created in bin folder
```

Now create Eclipse android project for your application

```
1. Go to project properties >> Android >> Add  >> Select Google play
service project
2. Now build your android project.
```

This should solve your "Dx Could not locate '../google-play-services_lib.jar'" problem.