# Could not locate google-play-services_lib.jar, but is there

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

All was ok with BaseGameUtils and GooglePlay services lib used with my project a day ago when I decided to update Eclipse to its latest version
Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

then I've started to get problems with the projects.
I did clean and rebuild the entire workspace, even restart Eclipse, fix project properties... add support library... but still I cannot solve the

```
> [... BaseGameUtils] Could not locate google-play-services_lib.jar'.
> This will not be added to the package
```

Of course, BaseGameUtils and GooglePlayServices are marked as "Is library" and I've checked the jar

```
file /media/dotteri/proyectos/google-play-services_lib/bin/google-play-services_lib.jar
/media/dotteri/proyectos/google-play-services_lib/bin/google-play-services_lib.jar: Java Jar file data (zip)
```

so, is there, but somehow Eclipse doesn't find the jar.

This person has the same problem like me: [Dx Could not locate '../google-play-services_lib.jar'. This will not be added to the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226204/dx-could-not-locate-google-play-services-lib-jar-this-will-not-be-added-to)

Am I missing something? Thank you

[Solved]

More or less solved. I just created a new project and I moved the source code there. I know this isn't the best way to solve it but it works. Thank you. The problem is not Eclipse.

Comment: Switch to Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, go to "Build Path>Configure Build Path" and then option "Android" on the left, below in that screen delete the google play services and add again.

Here is the path for google play services:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can copy de jar and put into LIBS folder, and then add to the build path....